# Java- Intersection point of a Polygon and Line

Tags: java, line, polygon, intersection

Is there any function that will give me the intersection point of a `Polygon` and `Line2D` ?

I have a Polygon and a line segment that I know intersect I want the actual value of the intersection point not a boolean answer.

Comment: I should probably add I know it intersects in exactly 1 place, because I know that one point is outside and one is inside the polygon.   But I do not know which segment of the polygon it intersects

Answer (score 10):

Here you are. The interesting methods are getIntersections and getIntersection. The former parses over all polygon segments and checks for intersections, the latter does the actual calculation. Do keep in mind that the calculation can be seriously optimized and doesn't check for division by 0. This will also work only for polygons. It could be adapted to work with other shapes if you introduce calculations for cubic and quadratic curves. It is assumed that Line2D.Double is used instead of Line2D.Float. A Set is used to avoid duplicate points (might occur on polygon corner intersections).

Please don't use this without extensive testing, since I've just hacked it together quickly and am not sure it's completely sound.

```
package quickpolygontest;

import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final Polygon poly = new Polygon(new int[]{1,2,2,1}, new int[]{1,1,2,2}, 4);
        final Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(2.5, 1.3, 1.3, 2.5);
        final Set<Point2D> intersections = getIntersections(poly, line);
        for(Iterator<Point2D> it = intersections.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            final Point2D point = it.next();
            System.out.println("Intersection: " + point.toString());
        }

    }

    public static Set<Point2D> getIntersections(final Polygon poly, final Line2D.Double line) throws Exception {

        final PathIterator polyIt = poly.getPathIterator(null); //Getting an iterator along the polygon path
        final double[] coords = new double[6]; //Double array with length 6 needed by iterator
        final double[] firstCoords = new double[2]; //First point (needed for closing polygon path)
        final double[] lastCoords = new double[2]; //Previously visited point
        final Set<Point2D> intersections = new HashSet<Point2D>(); //List to hold found intersections
        polyIt.currentSegment(firstCoords); //Getting the first coordinate pair
        lastCoords[0] = firstCoords[0]; //Priming the previous coordinate pair
        lastCoords[1] = firstCoords[1];
        polyIt.next();
        while(!polyIt.isDone()) {
            final int type = polyIt.currentSegment(coords);
            switch(type) {
                case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO : {
                    final Line2D.Double currentLine = new Line2D.Double(lastCoords[0], lastCoords[1], coords[0], coords[1]);
                    if(currentLine.intersectsLine(line))
                        intersections.add(getIntersection(currentLine, line));
                    lastCoords[0] = coords[0];
                    lastCoords[1] = coords[1];
                    break;
                }
                case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE : {
                    final Line2D.Double currentLine = new Line2D.Double(coords[0], coords[1], firstCoords[0], firstCoords[1]);
                    if(currentLine.intersectsLine(line))
                        intersections.add(getIntersection(currentLine, line));
                    break;
                }
                default : {
                    throw new Exception("Unsupported PathIterator segment type.");
                }
            }
            polyIt.next();
        }
        return intersections;

    }

    public static Point2D getIntersection(final Line2D.Double line1, final Line2D.Double line2) {

        final double x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4;
        x1 = line1.x1; y1 = line1.y1; x2 = line1.x2; y2 = line1.y2;
        x3 = line2.x1; y3 = line2.y1; x4 = line2.x2; y4 = line2.y2;
        final double x = (
                (x2 - x1)*(x3*y4 - x4*y3) - (x4 - x3)*(x1*y2 - x2*y1)
                ) /
                (
                (x1 - x2)*(y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2)*(x3 - x4)
                );
        final double y = (
                (y3 - y4)*(x1*y2 - x2*y1) - (y1 - y2)*(x3*y4 - x4*y3)
                ) /
                (
                (x1 - x2)*(y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2)*(x3 - x4)
                );

        return new Point2D.Double(x, y);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

There is `java.awt.geom.Area.intersect(Area)` using the constructor `Area(Shape)` with your Polygon and passing your `Line2D` as an Area to intersect will give you the Area which is intersected.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bear in mind that it might intersect at multiple places.

Let's call the line segment of the polygon P and the real line segment L.

We find the slope of each line (slope is m)

```
ml = (ly1-ly2) / (lx1-lx2);
mp = (ply-pl2) / (px1-px2);
```

Find the y intercept of each line

```
// y = mx+b where b is y-intercept
bl = ly1 - (ml*lx1);
bp = py1 - (pl*px1);
```

You can solve for the x value with:

```
x = (bp - bl) / (ml - mp)
```

Then plug that X into one of the equations to get the Y

```
y = ml * x + bl
```

Here's an implemented version of the algorithm

```
class pointtest {

    static float[] intersect(float lx1, float ly1, float lx2, float ly2,
                           float px1, float py1, float px2, float py2) {
        // calc slope
        float ml = (ly1-ly2) / (lx1-lx2);
        float mp = (py1-py2) / (px1-px2);       

        // calc intercept        
        float bl = ly1 - (ml*lx1);
        float bp = py1 - (mp*px1);  

        float x = (bp - bl) / (ml - mp);
        float y = ml * x + bl;

        return new float[]{x,y};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        float[] coords = intersect(1,1,5,5,1,4,5,3);
        System.out.println(coords[0] + " " + coords[1]);

    }
}
```

and results:

```
3.4 3.4
```

Comment: I should point out there are some conditions not covered here. What happens when the lines are the same? What happens when the lines don't intersect (equal slope)? What happens if the intersection occurs outside of the line segment? What if one of them is zero-slope? There's some special cases to cover that are left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

With great success, i used this approach:

```
Area a = new Area(shape1);
Area b = new Area(shape2);
b.intersect(a);
if (!b.isEmpty()) {
  //Shapes have non-empty intersection, so do you actions.
  //In case of need, actual intersection is in Area b. (its destructive operation)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not restricted to use the *Polygon* and *Line2D* Objects I would recommend to use [JTS](https://github.com/locationtech/jts).

- Create [LinearRing](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Polygon.html) geometry (your polygon).
- Create [LineString](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/LineString.html) geometry.
- Create intersection Point(s) using the [intersection](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#intersection(org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry)) method.

Simple code example:

```
// create ring: P1(0,0) - P2(0,10) - P3(10,10) - P4(0,10)
LinearRing lr = new GeometryFactory().createLinearRing(new Coordinate[]{new Coordinate(0,0), new Coordinate(0,10), new Coordinate(10,10), new Coordinate(10,0), new Coordinate(0,0)});
// create line: P5(5, -1) - P6(5, 11) -> crossing the ring vertically in the middle
LineString ls = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(new Coordinate[]{new Coordinate(5,-1), new Coordinate(5,11)});
// calculate intersection points
Geometry intersectionPoints = lr.intersection(ls);
// simple output of points
for(Coordinate c : intersectionPoints.getCoordinates()){
    System.out.println(c.toString());
}
```

Result is:

```
(5.0, 0.0, NaN)
(5.0, 10.0, NaN)
```