# Draw line between two centers (ov views), Without drawing on the views themself

Tags: android, canvas, view, line

I got a layout, where I need to draw line between two sub views (between the two centers), but witouth the line overlapping the views themself

I succeeded draw line between the two centers using:

```
final int lineStartX = ((LayoutParams) viewA.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin + (viewA.getMeasuredWidth() / 2);
final int lineStartY = ((LayoutParams) viewA.getLayoutParams()).topMargin + (viewA.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
final int lineEndX = ((LayoutParams) viewB.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin + (viewB.getMeasuredWidth() / 2);
final int lineEndY = ((LayoutParams) viewB.getLayoutParams()).topMargin + (viewB.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
canvas.drawLine(lineStartX, lineStartY, lineEndX, lineEndY, mLinePaint);
```

But the line is visible on the views area also.

Drawing the views on the line is not considered as solution, because the views background should be transparent

How do I achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: just calculate where this line intersects the view border and start drawing from that position

Comment: This is what I'm trying to find out , the intersect point :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184815/java-intersection-point-of-a-polygon-and-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally did it with my own implementation using Similar Triangles formula:
http://www.mathopenref.com/similartriangles.html

Answer (score 0):

```
lineStartX = viewA.getX + viewA.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
// Start from bottom of view
lineStartY = viewA.getY + viewA.getMeasuredHeight;
lineEndX = viewB.getX + viewB.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
// End at top of next view
lineEndY = viewB.getY;
canvas.drawLine(lineStartX, lineStartY, lineEndX, lineEndY, mLinePaint);
```

This works if your views are from top to bottom. It starts in the bottom middle of the top view and draws a line to the top middle of the bottom view.