# scanline: finding intersection points

Tags: java, scanline

I want to fill a polygon with the scanline algorith. for this I have to know all points where the scanline comes in contact with the polygon.
I wrote a loop for this, but its obviously not working (it never adds a point to the list which means it can't find any points which cuts the polygon)
I can create a Polygon and have all Edges from it.

Here is my code for getting the points of the scanline which intersect the polygon
xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax are the max points from the polygon. They are also correct. contains() checks, if a Point is inside the polygon, with using the java.awt.Polygon class. This is working too.
wasInside contains a boolean, which saves the old state, if the last point checked was inside the polygon or not.

```
boolean wasInside = false;
ArrayList<Point> intersectionPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
    for (int yTemp = ymin; yTemp <= ymax; yTemp++) {
        for (int xTemp = xmin; xTemp <= xmax; xTemp++) {
            if (wasInside != this.contains(new Point(xTemp, yTemp))) {
                intersectionPoints.add(new Point(xTemp, yTemp));
                wasInside = !wasInside;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run your code in a minimal frame. It works, there is nothing wrong with it.

I suggest you check these pitfalls:

- `Polygon.contains()` checks literally if a point is *inside*. So e.g. if your polygon is a rectangle starting at point (10, 10), then `contains(10, 10)` will return false. Only `contains(11, 11)` will return true. So you are not finding the real intersection points, but the first (and last) points inside.
- (Sorry, I've stumbled upon it myself) Make sure x and y are confused nowhere.
- Check the orientation: if you work with canvas, (0, 0) is the upper left point. But if you take a Math book and look at a Cartesian diagram, (0, 0) is the bottom left point - unless you have negative values. Could the orientation be confused somewhere?
- How do you check if some points were added to `intersectionPoints`? This should work: `System.out.println("Nb of intersection points found: " + intersectionPoints.size());`

After this, it should work for you. You might want to print out what is checked for better understanding:

```
for (int xTemp = xmin; xTemp <= xmax; xTemp++) {
    System.out.println("Check: " + xTemp + ", " + yTemp);
    if (wasInside != this.contains(new Point(xTemp, yTemp))) {
        System.out.println(" - Inside! Bash!");
        intersectionPoints.add(new Point(xTemp, yTemp));
        wasInside = !wasInside;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I had something mixed up with the xmin and xmax. Also the hint that it won't find points which are on the border of the polygon was important. to fix this, can I just say something like: `intersectionPoints.add(new Point(xTemp - 1, yTemp));` ? Because the x value is always 1 pixel to high in my opinion.

Comment: If your scanline _enters_ the polygon, the polygon's border will be 1 px to the left. If your scanline _leaves_ the polygon, the polygon's border will be the point just checked. But doing so, you still won't find the y axis intersection part properly. I'm sorry but for a proper solution, I think you will have to work either with `java.awt.geom.Line2D`, in order to find real intersection points, or with `java.awt.geom.Area.intersect(Area)`. Find a good start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184815/java-intersection-point-of-a-polygon-and-line).