# Scanline algorithm: how to calculate intersection points

Tags: java, scanline

I have to implement a scanline algorithm from our professor but I don't really understand how I get the intersection points from the scanline with a polygon.
Here is the algorithm:
[image: scanline algorithm]

I implemented my own polygon(with methods like `paint()`, `contains()` and so on) already and I have all edges from the polygon saved in an array like this:

```
int[] pointsX;
int[] pointsY;
```

and I have the min and max values for x and y saved in

```
int ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax;
```

So my first thought is that I have to create a scanline starting from `0,ymin` and check in a loop if the next point is inside the polygon. I implemented this method like this:

```
public boolean contains(Point test) {
    boolean result = false;

    java.awt.Polygon polygon = new java.awt.Polygon(pointsX, pointsY, pointsX.length);
    if (polygon.contains(test)) {
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

So when the next point is inside the polygon, I have a intersection point and so on. For this i have this loop:

```
ArrayList<Point> intersectionPoints = new ArrayList<>();
wasInside = false;
    for (int yTemp = ymin; yTemp <= ymax; yTemp++) {
        for (int xTemp = xmin; xTemp <= xmax; xTemp++) {
            if (wasInside != this.contains(new Point(xTemp, yTemp))) {
                intersectionPoints.add(new Point(xTemp, yTemp));
                wasInside = !wasInside;
            }
        }
    }
```

But I got a hint that this is no proper solution from [my stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467457/scanline-finding-intersection-points).

Can someone give me a hint, how I can start implementing the algorithm from my professor? Where do I get the x1,y1,x2,y2,c points? I know that these are the edges but how do I know which edges do I have to take?

EDIT:
OK, now I have all Edges sorted by their y values. Can I calculate the intersection points with the given formula Sx=x1+(x2-x1)/...?
My first try looks like this:

```
for (int c = ymin; c <= ymax; c++) {
        for (int xTemp = xmin; xTemp <= xmax; xTemp++) {
            for (int currentEdge = 0; currentEdge < edges.size() - 1; currentEdge++) {
                int x1 = edges.get(currentEdge).x;
                int x2 = edges.get(currentEdge + 1).x;
                int y1 = edges.get(currentEdge).y;
                int y2 = edges.get(currentEdge + 1).y;
                if ((y1 <= c && y2 > c) || (y2 <= c && y1 > c)) {
                    intersectionPoints.add(new Point((x1 + (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1) * (c - y1)),c));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But this seems to be wrong, because I get a lot of wrong Points in `intersectionPoints`.

Comment: The scanline agorithm usually maintains a set of "active edges" (namely, edges that are intersected by the current scanline). The "c" is just the current y-position of the scanline. And the (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) points are just the endpoints of one active edge. You have to sort all edges based on their y-values, and then let c walk from ymin to ymax, updating the set of active edges whenever you scan over a corner.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I added my try to calculate the intersectionPoints but there are mistakes in it. What am I doing wrong? I think I havn't understood this algorithm very well...

Comment: You never managed to say what you're trying to compute. "Scan line" is a class of algorithms that can compute many things. As @Marco13 said, the scan line itself is a data structure that normally includes the list of edges, line segments, arcs, etc. that it currently intersects.  The ends points of the edges, etc. and also intersections are processed as "events" that change the scan line.

Comment: Sorry  for this, I want to fill a Polygon with the scanline algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I calculated with `int` numbers and an `int` divided by another `int` results in inaccuracies. So just doing this with `double` numbers solved it.

This is how I calculate the intersection points:
`edges` is a `ArrayList<Point>` containing the edge points.
`ymin` is the lowest y value and `ymax`` the highest one.

```
for (int yTemp = ymin; yTemp <= ymax; yTemp++) {
        ArrayList<Point> intersectionPoints = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int p = 0; p < edges.size() - 1; p++) {
            int x1, x2, y1, y2;
            double deltax, deltay, x;
            x1 = edges.get(p).x;
            y1 = edges.get(p).y;
            x2 = edges.get(p + 1).x;
            y2 = edges.get(p + 1).y;

            deltax = x2 - x1;
            deltay = y2 - y1;

            int roundedX;
            x = x1 + deltax / deltay * (yTemp - y1);
            roundedX = (int) Math.round(x);
            if ((y1 <= yTemp && y2 > yTemp) || (y2 <= yTemp && y1 > yTemp)) {
                intersectionPoints.add(new Point(roundedX, yTemp));
            }
        }
        //for the last interval
        int x1, x2, y1, y2;
        x1 = edges.get(edges.size() - 1).x;
        y1 = edges.get(edges.size() - 1).y;
        x2 = edges.get(0).x;
        y2 = edges.get(0).y;
        if ((y1 <= yTemp && y2 > yTemp) || (y2 <= yTemp && y1 > yTemp)) {
            intersectionPoints.add(new Point(x1 + (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1) * yTemp - y1, yTemp));
        }
        //you have to sort the intersection points of every scanline from the lowest x value to thr highest
        Collections.sort(intersectionPoints, new SortXPoints());
        pointsOfScanline.add(intersectionPoints);
```

This will give you an ArrayList containing ArrayLists of scanline points for every Scanline. So you just have to draw them with `drawLine(x1, y2, x2, y2)`.