# Java Area intersection with Line

Tags: java, line, polygon, intersection

I'm trying to determine if a Polygon and Line intersect, and I'm getting incorrect answers based @Vikdor 's answer to the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184815/java-intersection-point-of-a-polygon-and-line).

I'm trying both Shape.intersectLine(Line2D) and Area.intersects(Area) and neither seem to work, although they do work properly when checking Rectangle to Rectangle. In the end, I need to be able to use Area.intersects(Area) since I'll need to check for simple Polygons intersecting Lines down the road. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class test4 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20,20,10,10);

        Rectangle rectThatShouldIntersect = new Rectangle(12,12,10,10);
        Rectangle rectThatShouldNotIntersect = new Rectangle(35,35,5,5);

        Line2D.Double lineThatShouldIntersect = new    Line2D.Double(25,0,25,50);
        Line2D.Double lineThatShouldNotIntersect = new Line2D.Double(10,0,10,50);

        System.err.println("Should be true: " + doesIntersectAsArea(new Area(rect), new Area(lineThatShouldIntersect)));
        System.err.println("Should be false: " + doesIntersectAsArea(new Area(rect), new Area(lineThatShouldNotIntersect)));

        System.err.println("Should be true: " + doesIntersectAsArea(new Area(rect), new Area(rectThatShouldIntersect)));
        System.err.println("Should be false: " + doesIntersectAsArea(new Area(rect), new Area(rectThatShouldNotIntersect)));

        System.err.println("Should be true: " + doesIntersect(rect, lineThatShouldIntersect));
        System.err.println("Should be false: " + doesIntersect(rect, lineThatShouldNotIntersect));

        System.err.println("Should be true: " + doesIntersect(rect, rectThatShouldIntersect));
        System.err.println("Should be false: " + doesIntersect(rect, rectThatShouldNotIntersect));

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();  

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.draw(rect);
        g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2d.draw(lineThatShouldIntersect);
        g2d.draw(rectThatShouldIntersect);
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.draw(lineThatShouldNotIntersect);           
        g2d.draw(rectThatShouldNotIntersect);   

        //code to save image
    }

    static public boolean doesIntersectAsArea(Area a, Area b)
    {
        a.intersect(b);
        return !a.isEmpty();
    }   

    static public boolean doesIntersect(Rectangle a, Line2D b)
    {
        a.intersectsLine(b);
        return !a.isEmpty();
    }   

    static public boolean doesIntersect(Rectangle a, Rectangle b)
    {
        a.intersects(b);
        return !a.isEmpty();
    }   
}
```

> Should be true: false
>   Should be false: false
>   Should be true: true
>   Should be false: false
>   Should be true: true
>   Should be false: true
>   Should be true: true
>   Should be false: true

[image]

**Am I missing something obvious here?**

Comment: You understand that the intersect() logic is based on segments?  That those segments are not extended to infinity?

Comment: @Paul Janssens - I'm note quite sure what you mean, the line segment definitely intersects two segments of the rect. I don't see what would be 'extended to infinity'

Comment: My question is if you only need to know if the segment intersects something, not if  the line through the segment intersects something.

Comment: @Paul Janssens I really just need to know if any part of the line enters the Rect - I don't need to know where specifically it enters, just whether if it happens or not.